# Percentage of a file C. How to fix sizes to stay in a limit?

Tags: c

I am trying to read a file in C and make some loading print that will show me how much of the file I have read so far (I am reading the file in chunks). My problem is when it comes to files larger (>100MBs), the loading crashes and I know that it is because there are limits of data types in C, yet I do not know how to fix it, or how to approach it.

Firstly, before I start the reading chunks the file part, I am computing the file size and then, I use a mathematical formula that would compute percentage since I make a sum of how much I have read and how much is total.

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
size_t nread;
char * buf  = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * CHUNK);
long total = 0;
fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
total = ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);

if (file)
    {
    while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, CHUNK, file)) > 0)
        {
                printf(" loading: %d \n", ftell(file)*100/total);
        }
    }

fclose(file);
```

The problem is at the sizes in C, since the files are larger then the int/long int limits, it overflows, is there a way to correctly display how much of the file I have parsed? I cannot store the result of "ftell(file)*100/total" in an int or long int.

Comment: You need to run this with a debugger, which will show you where exactly the crash occurs. And the problem is elsewhere is your code, there is nothong obviously wrong in the part of your code you show here. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: With the code you show there's three possibilities of undefined behavior and possible crashes: You using `file` without checking if it's a `NULL` pointer; `CHUNK` being to large (larger than the size of `buf`) leading to `fread` writing out of bounds; Or `total` being zero so you have a division by zero.

Comment: There are other possibilities of undefined behavior in your code, but ones that should not lead to crashes. For example arithmetic overflow for signed integers, and using the wrong `printf` format specifier for the arguments you pass.

Comment: Here is a [minimalist code](https://pastebin.com/MWbktM9v). In the bigger project, I have checked all the possibilities that you mentioned @Someprogrammerdude, but at the last comment, I guess you are correct. It does not crash as in the program stops, it goes for example like 6%.. 7% .. -7%, -8% and I guess it is overflowing, but how can I fix it? Since the files are larger than the limit in bytes for int, or long int, how can I fix the problem to keep the file proportionate in the limits? I have attached the code, at 200MBs file, it doesn't show correctly after a few seconds.

Comment: At my previous code, I have used safe_malloc, it should have been simply malloc.

Comment: @B.Ania please don't post links to your code in a comment, but [edit]  your question and put your code _there_.

Comment: @B.Ania and is there a reason why `CHUNK` is `10000000`? This is huge, `CHUNK` shouldn't be larger than a Mbyte or so. Did you try your code with `CHUNK` being smaller? But that's probably not the reason for the crash...

Comment: Are you on a system where `long` is 32 bits? Try using `size_t` and the `"%zu"` format specifier (or perhaps `unsigned long long` and the `"%llu"` format specifier).

Comment: Yes, I am implementing searching of large patterns (>10MBs) and I need the big chunks of the files, as big as the pattern since the files are a few GBs. The searching using chunks part is done searching first if the chunk is the pattern and then enlarging the chunk by chunk*2-1 and search if the pattern was cut somehow by the chunk when it was first taken, so that the search can be correct.

Comment: Yes, long is on 32 bits and unsigned long long int is on 8 bytes. I adjusted those and I still get the same problem. I was thinking if maybe is there a way to somehow proportionate the file size inside the limit of a long or int? Probably something like from 0 to 1 in int, this counts actually for x bytes read. And the total file size to be proportionate with the max limit of int. I don't know how to explain this well nor if it is possible.

Comment: @B.Ania instead of editing yout question and put "solved" you should rathe ranswer you own question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the data types. The answer was to use instead of int data type, the unsigned long long int datatype in order to compute the percentage.

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
size_t nread;
char * buf  = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * CHUNK);
unsigned long long total = 0, keeptrack_sum, percentage;
fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
total = ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);

if (file)
    {
    while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, CHUNK, file)) > 0)
        {

           keeptrack_sum += nread;
           percentage = keeptrack_sum*100/total
           printf(" loading: %d \n", percentage);
        }
    }

fclose(file);
```